# Component inside another Component in svelte

Tags: svelte

I have written the following component in svelte.

DataTableTest.svelte

```
<script>
  export let title;
  export let data;
  export let columns = [];
</script>

{title}
<table>
  {#if columns}
    <tr>
      {#each columns as c}
        <td>{c.label}</td>
      {/each}
    </tr>
  {/if}
  {#if data}
    <tbody>
      {#each data as d, i}
        <tr>
          {#each columns as c}
              <td>
              {@html d[c.property] ? d[c.property] : ''}
              </td>
          {/each}
        </tr>
      {/each}
    </tbody>
  {/if}
</table>
```

Now, I wanted to create this component, but within that, I again want to use the same component, something like below:

```
import DataTableTest from "./DataTableTest.svelte";

let columns = [
    {
      label: "ABC",
      property: "abc"
    },
    {
      label: "Items",
      property: "items"
    }
  ];


let data = [
  {
    "abc": "dsaaads",
    "items": "<DataTableTest title=\"dsaadsa\">",
  }

</script>


<DataTableTest title="Test" {data} {columns} />
```

But this line,

```
<DataTableTest title=\"dsaadsa\">
```

is not doing anything. If instead of DataTableTest, I used normal tags of html like div, etc., it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Afaik, you can't use svelte component inside the `@html` template.

However you could probably achieve something using [svelte:component](https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_component).

I made you a small example to demonstrate how to use it [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/3616effba1944ad7968d07e34e912bfb)

but basically you need to pass the element constructor inside your data structure and then instantiate it with the `svelte:component` element by passing the constructor of the custom element to the `this` prop.

```html
<script>
    import DataSet from './DataSet.svelte'
    export let data;
</script>

<DataSet {data} />
```

```html
<script>
    export let component; // pass the DataSet constructor to your component as prop here
    export let data;
</script>

<!-- your component here -->
<svelte:component this={component} {data} />
```

Comment: Does it not need to be yet again pass `data` to the `svelte:component` to allow more than 2 layers of depth?

Comment: In this exemple `data` only contain the constructor for the component, so the `this={data}` is enough. However if you want to pass other props to the `svelte:component`, you would need to pass them again yes.

Comment: But `<DataSet` takes in `{data} />`, so shouldn't it be `<svelte:component this={data} {data}` or something?

Comment: Actually you are right, it was pretty confusing. I edited my answer so hopefully the intent is clearer.